# get index of div on page load jquery

Tags: jquery, indexing

i have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/t2qkcoou/)

```
<div class="slider"> 
    <div class="slide"></div> 
    <div class="slide active"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div> 
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var listItem =  $(".slide.active");
  alert("Index: " + $(".slider").index(listItem));
});
```

Its giving me index -1
 how do i get index of class active on page load

Comment: by the way im using jssor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Index: " + $(".slide.active").index()); // return 1 (index start from 0)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're needing this `$('.slide')` instead of `$('.slider')`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var listItem =  $(".slide.active");
  alert("Index: " + $(".slide").index(listItem));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var listItem =  $(".slide.active");
  alert("Index: " + $(".slide").index(listItem));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider"> 
    <div class="slide"></div> 
    <div class="slide active"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div> 
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var listItem =  $(".slide.active");
  alert("Index: " + $(".slide").index(listItem));//use slide instesd of slider
});
```

Comment: i didn't see that..@Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal